# Monitor Document Downloads in SharePoint Foundation

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, auditing, download

Afternoon,

Is there a way to monitor/audit who downloads files in SharePoint Foundation either using something out of the box or by creating a workflow?

Thanks in advance
Steve

Answer (score 2):

While Auditing is not available from the UI in Foundation, you can access the Audit functionality and turn it on via the object model:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/53e79142-88c9-48f1-b5a5-a6259c9f6f97

If you notice in this post, Auditing is advertised as a feature of Foundation, but it takes a little extra work to enable and access it as opposed to Server:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/privacy-supplement-for-microsoft-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101108410.aspx